# How can I download a ZIP file using BeautifulSoup when the reference only shows "javascript:return true;"?

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I've been trying to write a script that downloads all the Forex pairs historical data (which are in ZIP format) from [here](https://www.histdata.com) at once.

The issue I have is that on the final page that contains the link to the file I do not get any reference to the file and href only shows:

href="javascript:return true;"

```
<a id="a_file" title="Download the zip data file" href="javascript:return true;" target="nullDisplay">HISTDATA_COM_MT_EURUSD_M1_201905.zipHISTDATA_COM_MT_EURUSD_M1_201905.zip</a>
```

[Here](http://www.histdata.com/download-free-forex-historical-data/?/metatrader/1-minute-bar-quotes/eurusd/2018) is a link to one of the download pages.

Comment: That means the actual download is probably triggered by a javascript that processes an `onClick` event. You will probably not be able to handle this with a simple web scraper. If you use your browser's debugging features you can see what URL is actually being fetched. I looked briefly, it seems to be sending a `POST` request, probably with information that identifies the file to download.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Scrape the download page, http://www.histdata.com/download-free-forex-historical-data/?/metatrader/1-minute-bar-quotes/eurusd/2018, and then get the value of name="tk" id="tk":

```
div style="display:none;">

<form id="file_down" name="file_down" target="nullDisplay" method="POST" action="/get.php">
    <input type="hidden" name="tk" id="tk" value="43a87a0c7e650addea7b01a17395a91c" />
    <input type="hidden" name="date" id="date" value="2018" />
    <input type="hidden" name="datemonth" id="datemonth" value="2018" />
    <input type="hidden" name="platform" id="platform" value="MT" />
    <input type="hidden" name="timeframe" id="timeframe" value="M1" />
    <input type="hidden" name="fxpair" id="fxpair" value="EURUSD" />
</form>
```

You also can get all the other ids...

```
def downloadzipfile(zipfiletype, zipfiletimeframe, zipfilefxpair, zipfileyear, zipfilemonth):
    postuseragent     = 'Mozilla/5.1'
    postorigin        = 'http://www.histdata.com'
    posturl           = postorigin+'/download-free-forex-historical-data/?/'+zipfiletype+'/'+zipfiletimeframe+'/'+zipfilefxpair+'/'+zipfileyear+'/'+zipfilemonth
    targetfolder      = 'C:/temp/'

    # Get the page and make the soup
    r = requests.get(posturl)
    data = r.text
    soup = BeautifulSoup(data, "lxml")
    #div style="display:none;"
    table = soup.find("div", style="display:none;")
    #print(table)
    try:
        posttk = table.find('input', {'id': 'tk'}).get('value')
        print(posttk)
    except:
        pass
    try:
        postdate = table.find('input', {'id': 'date'}).get('value')
        print(postdate)
    except:
        pass
    try:
        postdatemonth = table.find('input', {'id': 'datemonth'}).get('value')
        print(postdatemonth)
    except:
        pass
    try:
        postplatform = table.find('input', {'id': 'platform'}).get('value')
        print(postplatform)
    except:
        pass
    try:
        posttimeframe = table.find('input', {'id': 'timeframe'}).get('value')
        print(posttimeframe)
    except:
        pass
    try:
        postfxpair = table.find('input', {'id': 'fxpair'}).get('value')
        print(postfxpair)
    except:
        pass
```

Then you need to download the ZIP file with the request:

```
targetfilename    ='HISTDATA_COM_'+postplatform+'_'+postfxpair+'_'+posttimeframe+postdatemonth+'.zip'
targetpathfilename=targetfolder+targetfilename
print(targetfilename)
print(targetpathfilename)

resp    = requests.post(postorigin+'/get.php',
data    = {'tk': posttk, 'date': postdate, 'datemonth': postdatemonth, 'platform': postplatform, 'timeframe': posttimeframe, 'fxpair': postfxpair},
headers = {'User-Agent': postuseragent, 'Origin': postorigin, 'Referer': posturl})
```

And then write it to HDD and wait until it has finished writing:

```
# Wait here for the file to download
result = None
while result is None:
    with open(targetpathfilename, 'wb') as fpw:
        for chunk in resp.iter_content():
            fpw.write(chunk)
    time.sleep(1)
    result = 1
```

Put this all in a loop that goes through the FXpair you like with the time frame and time range, and then you can auto scrape the site:

```
print('Extract all ZIPfiles from history fx  ')
symbolsub = ["GBPJPY", "GBPUSD", "EURGBP"]
for symbolsubstring in symbolsub:
    for yearsub in range (2003, 2020):
        for monthsub in range(1, 13):
            filetype = 'ascii'
            filetimeframe = 'tick-data-quotes'
            currencypair = symbolsubstring
            fileyear = str(yearsub)
            filemonth = str(monthsub)
            print(filetype, filetimeframe, currencypair, fileyear, filemonth)
            downloadzipfile(filetype, filetimeframe, currencypair, fileyear, filemonth)
```

If you put the above pieces together and add the imports, you will have scrape software for the site.

Answer (score 0):

Use Chrome dev tools to explore what the exact request type is that is sent, and also look for other form data and headers that are being sent.

For your case, I found the headers and data in order to download the ZIP file. The below code should work fine. Just install the `requests` library before using the below code.

```
resp = requests.post(r'http://www.histdata.com/get.php',
data = {
    'tk': '43a87a0c7e650addea7b01a17395a91c',
    'date': '2018',
    'datemonth': '2018',
    'platform': 'MT',
    'timeframe': 'M1',
    'fxpair': 'EURUSD'
},
headers={
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.1',
    'Origin': 'http://www.histdata.com',
    'Referer': 'http://www.histdata.com/download-free-forex-historical-data/?/metatrader/1-minute-bar-quotes/eurusd/2018'
})

with open('output.zip', 'wb') as fpw:
    for chunk in resp.iter_content():
        fpw.write(chunk)
```

*Note: This can also download huge file since it does not read any data in memory.*

Comment: Thanks for reply, but your solution works only for EURUSD in year 2018. I checked other years and symbols and the only parameter that changes is tk. how can I find tk parameter for each page?